# PHP My SQL issue with google API

Tags: php, api

I am getting error "Can\'t use db :" when i open this file in local host . I have tried changing my sql to sqli. Does any one know why i geeting this error.
Will greatly appreciate any help on this, I have the code below. Thank you

```
<?php
require("connect.php");

// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];

// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysqli_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysqli_error());
}

// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysqli_error());
}

// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `markers`",
  mysqli_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysqli_query($query);

$result = mysqli_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("id", $row['id']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);

}

echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: Quite a clear error. The database you are trying to connect to doesn't exist. The fact you are not getting `Not connected` means the connection is fine but database is not. You might have database names with username as a prefix `username_db`

Comment: Also if you read up on the php website you will see you need to swap your parameters around for `mysqli_select_db` Change `$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($database, $connection);` to `$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);`

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with what you posted, and you seem to have adapted the old MySQL_ API method. The usage of the MySQLi_ API uses slightly different syntax.

Let's go through them, one at a time.

- `$connection=mysqli_connect (localhost, $username, $password);`

Now the first parameter is treated a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) and needs to be wrapped in quotes:

- `$connection=mysqli_connect ("localhost", $username, $password);`

Sidenote: You can use 4 parameters in one shot, rather than separate functions and using [`mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

From the manual:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

Then this:

- `$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($database, $connection);`

The connection parameter comes first with the MySQLi_ API.

Then this:

- `mysqli_error()`

That function requires the db connection parameter

Then this escaping function:

- `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

That also requires to have a connection be made and as the first parameter.

Then this line:

- `$result = mysqli_query($query);`

`mysqli_query()` requires a db connection also, and as the first parameter.

Here are references that you can look at in order to get your code working; **read them over carefully**:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

---

**Footnotes:**

This line `require("connect.php");` is unknown as to what that contains and what it's used for

Then `$database` is unknown as to where/how it is defined.

You're also using this twice:

```
$result = mysqli_query($query);

$result = mysqli_query($query);
```

Why? I don't know. But you can safely remove one (while passing db connection as the first parameter, as already outlined).

Make sure that all your GET arrays contain values.

Read up on `sprintf`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Should your present method fail you.

---

**Final notes:**

The `@` symbol in `@mysqli_fetch_assoc` is an error suppressor. You should remove it during testing.